# MS Access: Can't change the file type in the Save As dialog box

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an .mdb file created in access 2003 and I'd like to convert it to access 2007 .accdb
but when I go to the Save as dialog it lets me save the file only as it's current format(.mdb) and there isn't any additional file formats in the drop down box.

same thing happens when I create a new .accdb and try to save it as an 2003 .mdb file. I can't see anything but .accdb in the Save As file format drop down box.

I could probably run a VBA code to save as my wanted file format but it isn't optimal.

does any one knows what the solution might be?

Thank you,
Jake

Comment: Have you tried: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/convert-a-database-to-the-access-2007-file-format-HA010048406.aspx It mentions that you should first select the format. In 2010, you should use Save & Publish.

Comment: Thank you! you were right I had to save it through the Save & Publish.

Answer (score 0):

```
'PUT THIS IN A STANDARD CLASS MODULE FIRST

Option Compare Database 
Private mstrFileName As String 
Private mblnStatus As Boolean
'Declare needed functions

Private Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" _
(pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long

 Private Declare Function GetSaveFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "GetSaveFileNameA" _
 (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long

'Declare OPENFILENAME custom Type

Private Type OPENFILENAME

lStructSize As Long
hwndOwner As Long
hInstance As Long
lpstrFilter As String
lpstrCustomFilter As String
nMaxCustFilter As Long
nFilterIndex As Long
lpstrFile As String
nMaxFile As Long
lpstrFileTitle As String
nMaxFileTitle As Long
lpstrInitialDir As String
lpstrTitle As String
Flags As Long
nFileOffset As Integer
nFileExtension As Integer
lpstrDefExt As String
lCustData As Long
lpfnHook As Long
lpTemplateName As String
End Type

'Function needed to call the "Save As" dialog

Public Function SaveFileDialog(lngFormHwnd As Long, _
lngAppInstance As Long, strInitDir As String, _
strFileFilter As String) As Long

Dim SaveFile As OPENFILENAME
Dim X As Long

If IsMissing(strFileName) Then strFileName = ""

With SaveFile
.lStructSize = Len(SaveFile)
.hwndOwner = lngFormHwnd
.hInstance = lngAppInstance
.lpstrFilter = strFileFilter
.nFilterIndex = 1
.lpstrFile = String(257, 0)
'Use for a Default File SaveAs Name - [UD]
'.lpstrFile = "testfile.txt" & String(257 - Len("testfile.txt"), 0)
.nMaxFile = Len(SaveFile.lpstrFile) - 1
.lpstrFileTitle = SaveFile.lpstrFile
.nMaxFileTitle = SaveFile.nMaxFile
.lpstrInitialDir = strInitDir
.lpstrTitle = "Enter a Filename to Save As"        '[UD]
.Flags = 0
.lpstrDefExt = ".xls"   'Sets default file extension to Excel,
                     'in case user does not type it - [UD]
End With

X = GetSaveFileName(SaveFile)

If X = 0 Then
 mstrFileName = "none"
 mblnStatus = False
Else
 mstrFileName = Trim(SaveFile.lpstrFile)
  mblnStatus = True
End If
End Function
Public Property Let GetName(strName As String)
  mstrFileName = strName
 End Property
Public Property Get GetName() As String
  GetName = mstrFileName
 End Property
 Public Property Let GetStatus(blnStatus As Boolean)
mblnStatus = blnStatus
End Property
Public Property Get GetStatus() As Boolean
 GetStatus = mblnStatus
 End Property


'THEN WE'LL CALL IT LIKE

Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdTest_Click
Dim cDlg As New CommonDialogAPI         'Instantiate CommonDialog
Dim lngFormHwnd As Long
Dim lngAppInstance As Long
Dim strInitDir As String
  Dim strFileFilter As String
Dim lngResult As Long

lngFormHwnd = Me.Hwnd                           'Form Handle
lngAppInstance = Application.hWndAccessApp      'Application Handle
strInitDir = "C:\"                              'Initial Directory - [UD]

'Create any Filters here - [UD]

 strFileFilter = "Excel Files (*.xls)" & Chr(0) & "*.xls" & Chr(0) & _
             "ALL Files (*.*)" & Chr(0) & "*.* & Chr(0)"
             '"Text Files (*.csv, *.txt)" & _
             'Chr(0) & "*.csv; *.txt" & Chr(0)

 lngResult = cDlg.SaveFileDialog(lngFormHwnd, _
        lngAppInstance, strInitDir, strFileFilter)

If cDlg.GetStatus = True Then
 MsgBox "You chose the Filename of: " & cDlg.GetName    'Retrieve Filename - [UD]
Else
MsgBox "No file chosen."      '[UD]
End If

Exit_cmdTest_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_cmdTest_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error in cmdTest_Click()"
 Resume Exit_cmdTest_Click
 End Sub
```